# Process custom bulk action on admin Orders list in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have added a custom action in my woocommerce orders page like shown below, and I also have a custom order field "number of meals". Now what I want is when I select the orders in bulk and use that custom action then count of number of meals should get decreased by 1. 
For example if order id 1 & 2 had 15 & 12 number of meals respectively then after using the action it should become 14 & 11…

The screenshot of my orders page, the custom hook and the custom order field I created:

[image: screenshot of my orders page]

My code:

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'decrease_number_of_meals_by_1' );
function decrease_number_of_meals_by_1( $bulk_actions ) {
    $bulk_actions['decrease_number_of_meals'] = 'Decrease Number of Meals by 1';
    return $bulk_actions;
}

add_action( 'admin_action_decrease_number_of_meals', 'fire_my_hook' );
function fire_my_hook() {
    if( !isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) && !is_array( $_REQUEST['post'] ) )
        return;

    foreach( $_REQUEST['post'] as $order_id ) {

        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $no_of_meals = $order->get_post_meta( $order_id, '_wc_acof_{3}', true );
    }
}
```

I am stuck here and have no idea on how to do it further. 
Please guide me on how can I achieve this.

Comment: Actually i created that custom field using a plugin called "WooCommerce Admin Custom Order Fields" and in it's documentation it was mentioned that it's value can be fetched using this function, get_post_meta( $order_id, '_wc_acof_{id}', true ). @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i'm not sure in which table those fields are stored. i checked the order_itemmeta table but that field wasn't there.

Comment: Also the right meta key can't be `_wc_acof_{3}` but `_wc_acof_3` instead … so please check.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yes, i found the field in wp_postmeta table. you are right, i checked in the table it was "_wc_acof_3" like you said.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not using the right way and hooks. Also the right custom field meta key should be `_wc_acof_3` when using WooCommerce Admin Custom Order Fields plugin.

So try the following instead:

```
// Add a bulk action to Orders bulk actions dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'decrease_meals_orders_bulk_actions' );
function decrease_meals_orders_bulk_actions( $bulk_actions ) {
    $bulk_actions['decrease_meals'] = 'Decrease Number of Meals by 1';
    return $bulk_actions;
}

// Process the bulk action from selected orders
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'decrease_meals_bulk_action_edit_shop_order', 10, 3 );
function decrease_meals_bulk_action_edit_shop_order( $redirect_to, $action, $post_ids ) {
    if ( $action === 'decrease_meals' ){
        $processed_ids = array(); // Initializing

        foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            // Get number of meals
            $nb_meal = (int) get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_3', true );

            // Save the decreased number of meals ($meals - 1)
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_3', $nb_meal - 1 );

            $processed_ids[] = $post_id; // Adding processed order IDs to an array
        }

        // Adding the right query vars to the returned URL
        $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array(
            'decrease_meals' => '1',
            'processed_count' => count( $processed_ids ),
            'processed_ids' => implode( ',', $processed_ids ),
        ), $redirect_to );
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}

// Display the results notice from bulk action on orders
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'decrease_meals_bulk_action_admin_notice' );
function decrease_meals_bulk_action_admin_notice() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && isset($_GET['post_type']) 
    && 'shop_order' === $_GET['post_type'] && isset($_GET['decrease_meals']) {

        $count = intval( $_REQUEST['processed_count'] );

        printf( '<div class="notice notice-success fade is-dismissible"><p>' .
            _n( 'Decreased meals for %s Order.',
            'Decreased meals for %s Orders.',
            $count,
            'woocommerce'
        ) . '</p></div>', $count );
    }
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn, wow, that just worked perfectly. Thank you so much, i don't know what else to say. You are simply amazing.

Comment: I already did, I'd upvote it 1000 times if that would be an option. That was a bang on solution, thanks a lot .

Comment: Is this also possible for select fields created with "WooCommerce Admin Custom Order Fields"? For instance if you want certain orders to have a certain option selected within that custom field.

Comment: It's probably even simpler than the upper one. The trick would probably be to figure out selecting the right option. I'm trying to adapt you code right now and see how things turn out :)