# WooCommerce: Shop order bulk actions set variable on click

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, bulk

I've created a custom WooCommerce bulk action for my orders. My question is now: Is it possible to check when the bulk action gets pressed in the backend? Because when my custom action gets triggered I want to add a meta to the selected order. I just need to know if this is possible and if yes how can I hook in the selection function?

Code:

```
/**
 * Add custom bulk actions in woocommerce order overview
 */
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_shop_order_bulk_actions', 999 );
function custom_shop_order_bulk_actions( $actions ) {
    //Remove on hold, personal data and processing status mark
    unset( $actions['mark_on-hold'], $actions['remove_personal_data'], $actions['mark_processing'] );

    $actions['invoice-external']    = __( 'PDF Rechnung Extern' );

    return $actions;
}
```

My suggestion:

```
add_filter( 'hook_into_bulk_action-invoice-external', 'do_something' )
function do_something() {
    global $abc = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order` filter hook this way:

```
// Process the bulk action from selected orders
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'process_bulk_actions_edit_shop_order', 10, 3 );
function process_bulk_actions_edit_shop_order( $redirect_to, $action, $post_ids ) {
    if ( $action === 'invoice-external' ){
        // Add (or update) order post meta data
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_your_meta_key', $some_value );
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

See this related answer: [Process custom bulk action on admin Orders list in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916661/process-custom-bulk-action-on-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce/52917368#52917368)