# Process multiple Custom bulk action on Woocommerce admin Orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce using the plugin [Admin Custom Order Fields](https://woocommerce.com/products/admin-custom-order-fields/), I have a added a custom fields "Rebates Status" with 3 values "No Rebates", "Unpaid" and "Paid", on WooCommerce admin Orders list.

[image]

I have also displayed that on the view order screen just like the screenshot below:

[image]

Now I would like to bulk update the Rebates Status on selected orders, just as wooCommerce allow to do it for orders status bulk change.

Based on *"[Process custom bulk action on admin Orders list in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916661/process-custom-bulk-action-on-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce/52917368#52917368)"* answer thread, I successfully added the 3 Rebates statuses on the bulk edit dropdown *(as you can see on the first screenshot)*:

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'decrease_meals_orders_bulk_actions' );
function decrease_meals_orders_bulk_actions( $bulk_actions ) {
    $bulk_actions['mr_norebates'] = 'Mark Transactions as No Rebates';
    $bulk_actions['mr_unpaid'] = 'Mark Transactions as Unpaid';
    $bulk_actions['mr_paid'] = 'Mark Transactions as Paid';
    return $bulk_actions;
}
```

But no changes are applied when I try to bulk update the Rebates status for selected orders.

The meta key for Rebates Status is `_wc_acof_2`

Im stuck also and don't know how to solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us, in your question, the code that you have used to display your custom bulk actions  please...

Comment: hi sir, please check my answer and I still need help, if this truly ok...

Comment: You can still answer sir, I will delete my answer soon, Im still waiting with a simplified one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the complete, compact and optimized way to make it work for each of the 3 actions, to bulk update your custom "Rebate status" displaying a summary notice:

```
// Your settings in a function
function custom_admin_orders_bulk_actions( $labels = false ){
    $domain = 'woocommerce';
    return array(
        'mr_norebates'  => $labels ? __('No Rebates', $domain) : 'norebates',
        'mr_unpaid'     => $labels ? __('Unpaid', $domain)     : 'unpaid',
        'mr_paid'       => $labels ? __('Paid', $domain)       : 'paid',
    );
}

// Display the custom actions on admin Orders bulk action dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'set_transactions_orders_bulk_actions' );
function set_transactions_orders_bulk_actions( $bulk_actions ) {
    foreach( custom_admin_orders_bulk_actions(true) as $key => $label ) {
        $bulk_actions[$key] = sprintf( __('Mark Transactions as %s', 'woocommerce'), $label );
    }
    return $bulk_actions;
}

// Process the bulk action from selected orders
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'set_transactions_bulk_action_edit_shop_order', 10, 3 );
function set_transactions_bulk_action_edit_shop_order( $redirect_to, $action, $post_ids ) {
    $actions = custom_admin_orders_bulk_actions();

    if ( in_array( $action, array_keys($actions) ) ) {
        $processed_ids = array(); // Initializing

        foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            // Save the new value
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_2', $actions[$action] );

            $processed_ids[] = $post_id; // Adding processed order IDs to an array
        }

        // Adding the right query vars to the returned URL
        $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array(
            'rebate_action'   => $action,
            'processed_count' => count( $processed_ids ),
            'processed_ids'   => implode( ',', $processed_ids ),
        ), $redirect_to );
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}

// Display the results notice from bulk action on orders
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'set_transactions_bulk_action_admin_notice' );
function set_transactions_bulk_action_admin_notice() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'shop_order' === $_GET['post_type']
    && isset($_GET['rebate_action']) && isset($_GET['processed_count']) && isset($_GET['processed_ids']) ) {

        foreach( custom_admin_orders_bulk_actions(true) as $key => $label ) {
            if (  $_GET['rebate_action'] === $key ) {

                $count = intval( $_GET['processed_count'] );

                printf( '<div class="notice notice-success fade is-dismissible"><p>' .
                    _n( '%s selected order updated to "%s" rebate status.',
                    '%s selected orders updated to "%s" rebate status.',
                    $count, 'woocommerce' )
                 . '</p></div>', $count, $label );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Based on: [Process custom bulk action on admin Orders list in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916661/process-custom-bulk-action-on-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce/52917368#52917368)

Comment: Wonderful! I've been trying to achieve bulk actions on orders for a select field created with "Admin Custom Order Fields" as well and your solution does exactly what I want!

Just one thing. The project is in German and therefore some field's labels contain ä, ö, ü and & etc. I recognized that the values return empty if the bulk action is containing one of these characters. Any idea?

Comment: I figured it out. This had nothing to do with the German umlauts. I checked the database and recognized that I had differing values of how "Admin Custom Order Fields" handled my statuses before. I checked that all are identical. My mistake...
Your code above works pefectly for this case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

actually I made it work with the help of your code, but its too long, I appreciate if you can make it simple...

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'decrease_meals_orders_bulk_actions' );
function decrease_meals_orders_bulk_actions( $bulk_actions ) {
    $bulk_actions['mr_norebates'] = 'Mark Transactions as No Rebates';
    $bulk_actions['mr_unpaid'] = 'Mark Transactions as Unpaid';
    $bulk_actions['mr_paid'] = 'Mark Transactions as Paid';
    return $bulk_actions;
}

// Process the bulk action from selected orders
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'decrease_meals_bulk_action_edit_shop_order', 10, 3 );
function decrease_meals_bulk_action_edit_shop_order( $redirect_to, $action, $post_ids ) {
    if ( $action === 'mr_norebates' ){
        $processed_ids = array(); // Initializing

        foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            // Get number of meals
            $nb_meal = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_2', true );

            // Save the decreased number of meals ($meals - 1)
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_2', $nb_meal = 'norebates' );

            $processed_ids[] = $post_id; // Adding processed order IDs to an array
        }

        // Adding the right query vars to the returned URL
        $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array(
            'mr_norebates' => 'No Rebates',
            'processed_count' => count( $processed_ids ),
            'processed_ids' => implode( ',', $processed_ids ),
        ), $redirect_to );
    }

    elseif ( $action === 'mr_unpaid' ){
        $processed_ids = array(); // Initializing

        foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            // Get number of meals
            $nb_meal = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_2', true );

            // Save the decreased number of meals ($meals - 1)
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_2', $nb_meal = 'unpaid' );

            $processed_ids[] = $post_id; // Adding processed order IDs to an array
        }

        // Adding the right query vars to the returned URL
        $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array(
            'mr_unpaid' => 'Unpaid',
            'processed_count' => count( $processed_ids ),
            'processed_ids' => implode( ',', $processed_ids ),
        ), $redirect_to );
    }
    elseif ( $action === 'mr_paid' ){
        $processed_ids = array(); // Initializing

        foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            // Get number of meals
            $nb_meal = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_2', true );

            // Save the decreased number of meals ($meals - 1)
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_2', $nb_meal = 'paid' );

            $processed_ids[] = $post_id; // Adding processed order IDs to an array
        }

        // Adding the right query vars to the returned URL
        $redirect_to = add_query_arg( array(
            'mr_paid' => 'Paid',
            'processed_count' => count( $processed_ids ),
            'processed_ids' => implode( ',', $processed_ids ),
        ), $redirect_to );
    }
    return $redirect_to;

}

// Display the results notice from bulk action on orders
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'decrease_meals_bulk_action_admin_notice' );
function decrease_meals_bulk_action_admin_notice() {
    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['mr_norebates'] ) ) return; // Exit

    $count = intval( $_REQUEST['processed_count'] );

    printf( '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>' .
        _n( 'Selected %s transaction updated.',
        'Selected %s transactions updated.',
        $count,
        'mr_norebates'
    ) . '</p></div>', $count );
```

Comment: Your third function is incomplete and display a notice only for "No rebates" orders changed… I have answered, compacting and optimizing your code.