# WordPress - hook into bulk actions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any way to hook into bulk actions in WordPress (WooCommerce)?

Say, when 3 products are edited using the bulk functionality, I'd like to have an action
which is ideally passed all the products that were edited.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: what about this reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52917368/6536335 ?

Comment: another reference - https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/10/04/custom-bulk-actions/

Comment: Thank you! I can't get it to work for wc products... what's the filter? I tried handle_bulk_actions-edit-product and handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_product, but those don't seem to work.